# Transparent navigation Bar (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationbar

I did the following to make the navigationbar just white.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```

So I set every UIViewController to "not under top/bot bar". This looks as I want. But when I make an UIImagePicker for example it looks like this:
[image: navigation Bar]

So I tried the following:

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePicker()
imagePicker.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

But it doesnt work. How I have to do this?

Kindly Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

into my AppDelegate.

Thank you to Fonix and dfd

Answer (score 8):

Isnt the navigation bar white by default? going like

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```

is setting the background to an image with no data, so it will be transparent. If you really need to set the colour of the nav bar, use

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
```

instead of setting the background to an image. You may need

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

inside viewDidLoad for each viewController, but try without it first

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

// these next lines aren't needed if you like the default

UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black]  // shouldn't be needed, but if you want something 
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

I'm pretty sure you need to set the isTranslucent to false.